# Parsing a json reponse in ruby to terminal

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read/parse a json response to the terminal as a first step before getting my code to do something useful with the information (read it and return either true or false for a certain piece of info).

So far this is my code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "json"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.navigate.to "http://web.address/example/"
# waits for certain code/elements to load
sleep(3)

driver.execute_script("return function.toserver.makesresponse()")
testvar = driver.execute_script("return JSON.stringify(filename)")
# the file name is   specific
puts testvar
sleep(10)
driver.quit
```

The output of 'testvar' is just '{}' in the terminal. When I send the function or method to the server, where does the json response 'go'? Is there another way of accessing that json file in the browser?

Comment: May be helpful, if you could give us the url you are hitting..

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - it is a test URL for the company I work for.